# How to perform excel operation via Python?

Tags: python, windows, excel, csv

I am working on a project and want to write excel and csv files from python 3 on my windows server. Can anyone help if the goal could be achieved from python ?
A HOW would be utterly appreciated.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi Avi, questions of this type belong on StackOverflow. (Admins will migrate). Though chances are it's a duplicate and answered already.

Comment: Look up xlrd python module.

Comment: there are some nice api..check them out! google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a great built-in module called csv that will help you with the csv files. There are examples [here](http://pymotw.com/2/csv/index.html), and the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is (as always) your first/close-to-best reference.

As for Excel, I wrote some wrappers for the `xlrd` and `xlwt` modules and posted them here: [Python script to manipulate excel sheets by auto-filling spaces in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567545/python-script-to-manipulate-excel-sheets-by-auto-filling-spaces-in-columns/14575047#14575047) The answer in that question contains examples of how to use the wrappers, and the wrappers themselves are examples of how to cal xlrd and xlwt. The wrappers I wrote assume square tables (possibly with nulls), one table per worksheet. Anything more exotic than that and you're on your own :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [website](http://www.python-excel.org/) dedicated to python/excel interop

Answer (score 2):

Python has a built-in library called [csv](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html). This library can read csv files and convert them to python data structures, and vice versa. An example (from python documentation):

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```